# Deleting grouped row with other value than desired value

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Is there a way to delete the variable `id` with other `dx` than "I10"?

```
id            dx
1      I10, E70
2           I10
2           I10
3      I10, J15
3      I10, Z50
3      I10, B24
3           I10
4           I10
4           I10
5      I10, Z80
6           I10
7      B65, I10
7 H58, J30, I10
7      M24, I10
8           I10
8           I10
```

The result should look like this. It should only has `id` with `dx` as "I10" only.

```
id            dx
2           I10
2           I10
4           I10
4           I10
6           I10
8           I10
8           I10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the id's where all the values are `'I10'`

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(all(dx == 'I10'))

#     id dx   
#  <int> <chr>
#1     2 I10  
#2     2 I10  
#3     4 I10  
#4     4 I10  
#5     6 I10  
#6     8 I10  
#7     8 I10
```

Base R :

```
subset(df, ave(dx == 'I10', id, FUN = all))
```

`data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(dx == 'I10')], id]
```

---

If you have more than one value to filter it would be better to split the comma-separated values into different rows.

```
values_to_filter <- c("I10", "E70")

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(dx, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(dx %in% values_to_filter)) %>%
  group_by(row, id) %>%
  summarise(dx = toString(dx)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

#     id dx      
#  <int> <chr>   
#1     1 I10, E70
#2     2 I10     
#3     2 I10     
#4     4 I10     
#5     4 I10     
#6     6 I10     
#7     8 I10     
#8     8 I10
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L), dx = c("I10,E70", "I10", "I10", "I10,J15", 
"I10,Z50", "I10,B24", "I10", "I10", "I10", "I10,Z80", "I10", 
"B65,I10", "H58,J30,I10", "M24,I10", "I10", "I10")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! What if I wanted to include the "id" with "dx" with "I10" or "E70", so the result data would include "id" 1 too?